# How to detect if ValueEventListener has fetched data or not in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using following code to fetch the data from Firebase DB but as it makes network request in background thread so I want to wait till it completes the request and get a value. For example,

```
boolean isAvailable=false;
    usernameReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        isAvailable = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
if(isAvailable){
       //do something here
}
else{
      //do something here 
}
```

This snippet always execute the else part so I want to wait till the variable `isAvailable` get the value from database then further Execution will take place.

Comment: Use an interface for that.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create an interface like this:

```
public interface IsAvailableCallback {
    void onAvailableCallback(boolean isAvailable);
}
```

Suppose your above code is in this method which takes interface object to trigger callback like :

```
public void isAvailable(IsAvailableCallback callback) {
    boolean isAvailable=false;
    usernameReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    isAvailable = true;
                    //this will trigger true
                    callback.onAvailableCallback(isAvailable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //this will trigger false
                    callback.onAvailableCallback(isAvailable);
                }
            });                
}
```

Call this method like :

```
isAvailable(new IsAvailableCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAvailableCallback(boolean isAvailable) {
        //you will get callback here, Do your if condition here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You... Clearly Explained...!