# Why is "If Condition" inside onClick not working when using Firebase Database in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
a2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //below
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ra2 = dataSnapshot.child("a2").getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //fetching face value
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                rface = dataSnapshot.child("face").getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //fetching nothingdb which is equals to "zero" in Firebase by default.

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                nothing = dataSnapshot.child("nothingdb").getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //fetching addeddb which is equals to "one" in Firebase by default.

        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                added = dataSnapshot.child("addeddb").getValue(String.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        //starting if condition
        if (ra2==nothing){

            if (rface==nothing){
                a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded);{
                    Firebase refChild = ref2.child("a2");
                    refChild.setValue("rounda2");
                    refChild = ref2.child("face");
                    refChild.setValue("one");
                }

                else if (rface==added) {
                    a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.crossed);
                    {
                        Firebase refChild = ref2.child("a2");
                        refChild.setValue("crossa2");
                        refChild = ref2.child("face");
                        refChild.setValue("zero");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am trying to use the above written code so that once I click on the button the background image of the button is changed based on the data present in the Firebase but the If Condition is not working for reason.

It just ignores `if (ra2==nothing){` and also the next if conditions.

Comment: What is data type of ra2 and nothing?

Comment: Compare using equals method

Comment: A more significant problem is that the `onDataChange()` callbacks are asynchronous.  `ra2`, `nothing`, `added`, and `rface` will not contain valid results when you compare them for equality because the `onDataChange()` methods will not yet have executed.  See this answer for more explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41409942/4815718

Comment: Check this question, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260334/how-to-detect-if-valueeventlistener-has-fetched-data-or-not-in-firebase

Comment: can you share structure of the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener `onDataChange()` callbacks are asynchronous. `ra2`, `nothing`, `added`, and `rface` will not contain valid results when you compare them for equality because the `onDataChange()` methods will not yet have executed.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41409942/4815718) to a related question explains the execution order in more detail.

In addition, to compare Strings for equality you cannot use the `==` operator.  You must use the [equals()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method or [TextUtils.equals()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#equals(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: Thank you very much @qbix, I did not knew about the asynchronous callbacks. It worked after reframing my problem. And thanks the advice on == operator.

Answer (score 1):

@qbix's answer is true, your `if` condition actually work but it does not receive the value of `ra2`, `rface`, `nothing`, and `added` yet.

Also, why should you create 4 different `ValueEventListener` while you listening to the same reference? You can use just 1 listener then put your `if` condition inside `onDataChange`, like this:

```
a2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ra2 = dataSnapshot.child("a2").getValue(String.class);
                rface = dataSnapshot.child("face").getValue(String.class);
                nothing = dataSnapshot.child("nothingdb").getValue(String.class);
                added = dataSnapshot.child("addeddb").getValue(String.class);

                //starting if condition
                if (ra2.equals(nothing)) {
                    if (rface.equals(nothing)) {
                        a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded);
                        Firebase refChild = ref2.child("a2");
                        refChild.setValue("rounda2");
                        refChild = ref2.child("face");
                        refChild.setValue("one");
                    } else if (rface.equals(added)) {
                        a2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.crossed);
                        Firebase refChild = ref2.child("a2");
                        refChild.setValue("crossa2");
                        refChild = ref2.child("face");
                        refChild.setValue("zero");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });       
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, for the advice on ValueEventListener.